# "Type additional comments if any." Is this construction acceptable?

Tags: grammar

I want to say "Type additional comments if any", but I find the sentence to contain a redundancy at "if any." I, however, do not want to give an impression that you "have to" write additional comments. How about "Feel free to type comments if any"? or do you have any other suggestions?

If this post itself contains grammatical errors, please feel free to correct them!

Comment: At the very least, place a comma (,) after *comments*; this helps separate the *if any* from the main part of the sentence and helps it seem more optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Type additional comments if any

It makes sense since the you are trying to say

> If you have any additional comments, type them.

This seems fine as phrase to instruct the reader. You might also want to say

> Include additional comments, if any.

This seems like a typical line you might find in a application or survey.

> 2. Feel free to type comments if any.

seems friendlier and less commanding than 1. 2. sounds more optional than 1. So it is up to you how you want to sound.

Comment: Thank you, Max. English connotation issue gets so tricky.

Comment: Yes, they do unfortunately. You are welcome to wait much longer before you accept an answer. This gives other users a chance to respond with different and possibly better answers. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I personally would not use the verb "type". It feels unnatural and I think of the physical action of typing. It would be like saying "please walk to teacher's room."

Comment: @Leo  Yeah, some what unnatural, but not too bad. Seems passable to me. I see no big problem with it. Also, there is no "please" involved. It would be "Walk to the teacher's room". Makes sense to me.